# Visual Studio Code takes years to load and randomly crash on Fedora 36

Tags: visual-studio-code, fedora

I'm having troubles using Visual Studio Code recently.
The app worked correctly some days ago, but now it takes years to load, the pop-up "The window is not responding" has enough time to pop 2 or 3 times sometimes, and the whole app crashes sometimes as well. I don't remember installing something that could cause my VS Code to crash this way. I tried disabling some of my extensions that could use memory, but nothing changed.
I tried to launch it with --disable-gpu, but it never launched. --disable-extensions all never launched either. The only error on launch with --verbose is "CodeWindow: detected unresponsive"
I also tried to remove my vscode config and the whole program but i'm still facing the same issue, deleted all files in $HOME/.vscode and in /home/$USER/.config/Code and nothing changed. I have no antivirus installed on my computer as I know (`dnf list installed | grep -i antivirus` return nothing too)

here is my "Help: About":

```
Version: 1.86.1
Commit: 31c37ee8f63491495ac49e43b8544550fbae4533
Date: 2024-02-07T09:07:19.849Z
Electron: 27.2.3
ElectronBuildId: 26495564
Chromium: 118.0.5993.159
Node.js: 18.17.1
V8: 11.8.172.18-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 6.2.15-100.fc36.x86_64
```

Comment: any antivirus on your machine? Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**.

Comment: what about backing up your user config, then purging your installation and reinstalling?

Comment: Usually I have this nightmare with McAfee AV, if you have any similar  AV it could be an issue.

Comment: There's an update - does that work better?  Have you tried VS Code - Insiders?  Both work fine on my Fedora 36 and 38 systems.  It's like drinking from a fire hydrant, but you could also launch using `strace` to see if something is "hanging".